# codeigniter route for all controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

i have a website with different controllers shops,articles,basic pages (e.g about, home, faq, etc)

i need a way to display items in my website like this

normally it is like this

```
www.site.com/category/sub-category/article-title
```

but i need it like this

```
www.site.com/article-title
```

normally the shop is like this

```
www.site.com/shops/shop-name
```

but i would need it like this

```
www.site.com/shop-name
 OR shop-name.site.com
```

an excerpt of my current route rule

```
$route['category/(:any)'] = 'ads/cat/$1';
$route['category/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'ads/cat/$1/$2';

$route['shops/(:any)'] = 'shops/$1';
$route['shops/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'shops/$1/$2';

$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'site/$1/$2';
$route['(:any)'] = 'site/$1';
```

Comment: how you distinguish `www.site.com/abc` is article or shop name?

Comment: i actually dont know, that is why i asked. i have seen alot of website do it, mostly shopping sites that offer shops to sellers

Comment: In that case article(ads) and shop(shops) should be one controller and your controller will decide it is article(match from article table) or shop(match from shop table) and display corresponding view.I hope you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [URI routing](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html). The drawback is that you'll have to add each route by hand.

```
$route['article-title'] = 'category/sub-category/article-title'
$route['article/(:any)'] = 'article/$1'
```

You could also try [remapping](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) inside the controller with `_remap()`.

This [article](http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-remove-index-php-minimize-url/) explains things pretty thoroughly.

Comment: i post articles throught the webapp cms, do i have to edit the route every time i do post?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to if you've done your regex properly.